# Is it possible to sort documents on a connected "foreign" index in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch version 7.0

Hello and good day!

I have an indices named **socialmedia** and **influencers** with the following sample documents

**socialmedia**:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "smp_id": "5",
    "content" : "Sample Content 1"
},
{
    "_id": 3,
    "smp_id": "10",
    "content" : "ABCs..."
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "smp_id": "15",
    "content" : "XYZs..."
},
```

**influencers**

```
{
    "smp_id": "5",
    "name" : "Aaron"
},
{
    "smp_id": "10",
    "name" : "Henry"
},
{
    "smp_id": "15",
    "name" : "Zandaya"
}
```

**SCENARIOS**

1. I can't make any *"reindex"* (or changing the mappings) approach anymore because the **socialmedia** index contains more than 50 million documents as of writing

**OBJECTIVE**

I want to sort my **socialmedia** documents according to the **influencers'** name alphabetically, is it possible?

Comment: Hello. In one query without reindexing no. Just to be curious, why you couldnot reindex? this is pretty easy, 50M is not a lot. You have a one to one, one to many relationship between socialmedia  and  influencers, how many influencer to you have?

Comment: there are other fields I have omitted and a lot of more nested objects that's why the last time we made a reindex session, it took us 10 hours. so it would eat a lot of our time just to go back to the normal dev time

Comment: by the way, our original database is MySQL based

Comment: Yes i guessed it was sql model :). You could just add a name field in your socialmedia index. Using partial update it will be pretty fast. And then you could make your query (trivial). Of course i dont know if name need to be updated regularly

Comment: hhhmmmm seems there's no other way to connect these 2 indices. the only resolve is to reindex the **socialmedia** index and add the **influencers'** names there haha

got it, thank you very much